Algorithm to get the solution of an assignment problem with “singles” on both sides
I’m looking for an algorithm to find a solution to the assignment problem where agents on both sides (say, men and women) can stay unassigned (“singles”). This means that every agent on both sides has some value in staying single (we can normalize it to zero), and each potential pair also has some value. The target is to find the allocation that maximizes the total value.
More formally, there are $I$ men and $J$ women. The value of an unassigned man and woman is $u_{i0}$ and $u_{0j}$, respectively. The value of a matched pair is $u_{ij}$. The goal is to find the allocation $\mu_{ij}$ (every man is matched to up to one woman and vice versa) that maximizes the sum of the values.
Bonus:

The algorithm works well with sparse matrixes (i.e., only a small number of potential pairs are feasible)

It is a modification of the auction algorithm



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hope it is better now

This is a classical game theory problem from what I see.
I'll first define the game frame:

2 sets of players: $J = {1,2,3...j}$, $I = {1,2,3...i}$.
Strategy of each man: Either match with a woman $j \in J$ or stay single.
Strategy of each woman: Either match with man $i \in I$ or stay single.
Each player has a utility from some outcome. If two players ($i$ and $j$) match together, they both receive a utility (or payoff) of $u_{ij}$. However different players have different preferences so they both have to find the option of matching valuable. If a player (either $i$ or $j$) decided to say single, they receive a utility of $u_{i0}$ or $u_{0j}$ depending on the player. If they find utility in this option, they'll go for it.
Outcomes: As we mentioned, they're two. Either a player matches with someone or stays single.

We also have constraints. These are that a player can either be matched with one other player only or stay single. Mathematically we can express that by defining $\mu_{ij}$ to be a binary variable such that is equal to 1 if man $i$ is matched with woman $j$ and is equal to 0 if otherwise. I'll also define 2 new variables: $\mu_{i0}$ and $mu_{0j}$ which are also binary variables, being equal to 1 if man $i$ or woman $j$ is single and 0 if otherwise. Thus the constraints are:
$$ \mu_{i0} + \sum_{j=1}^{J} \mu_{ij} \le 1$$
The one above constraining each man to either being with one woman or single. And the below one constraining each woman to either being with one man or single.
$$ \mu_{0j} + \sum_{i=1}^{I} \mu_{ij} \le 1 $$
The objective is to maximize the total utility. That is:
$$ Max(\sum_{i=1,j=1}^{I,J}u_{ij} \mu_{ij} + \sum_{i=1}^{I} u_{i0} \mu_{i0} + \sum_{j=1}^{J} u_{0j} \mu_{0j}) $$
Optimizing for the maximum value can be done using linear programming. One could define 2 matrices of utility functions for every $i$ and $j$, as well as the number of men and women. Here's a simple example:
Say we have 3 men and 3 women.
$I = 3; J = 3$
Utility matrix of matched pairs:
$$ u = \begin{bmatrix}
u_{11} & u_{12} & u_{13} \\\
u_{21} & u_{22} & u_{23} \\\
u_{31} & u_{32} & u_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}$$
Utility matrices of being single:
$$ u_{i0} = \begin{bmatrix} 
u_{10} & u_{20} & u_{30} 
\end{bmatrix}, u_{0j} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
u_{01} & u_{02} & u_{03}
\end{bmatrix}$$
You could use the "pulp" module in phyton to solve it.
import pulp

I = 3
J = 3

u = [
    [10, 5, 7],  # Plug whatever values you want in here
    [8, 4, 6], 
    [9, 7, 5]    
]

u_i0 = [3, 2, 4]
u_0j = [1, 5, 2]

prob = pulp.LpProblem("Problem", pulp.LpMaximize)

mu_ij = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("mu_ij", (range(I), range(J)), cat='Binary')
mu_i0 = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("mu_i0", range(I), cat='Binary')
mu_0j = pulp.LpVariable.dicts("mu_0j", range(J), cat='Binary')

prob += pulp.lpSum([u[i][j] * mu_ij[i][j] for i in range(I) for j in range(J)]) + \
        pulp.lpSum([u_i0[i] * mu_i0[i] for i in range(I)]) + \
        pulp.lpSum([u_0j[j] * mu_0j[j] for j in range(J)])

for i in range(I):
    prob += pulp.lpSum([mu_ij[i][j] for j in range(J)]) + mu_i0[i] <= 1

for j in range(J):
    prob += pulp.lpSum([mu_ij[i][j] for i in range(I)]) + mu_0j[j] <= 1

prob.solve()

print("Matching:")
for i in range(I):
    for j in range(J):
        if pulp.value(mu_ij[i][j]) == 1:
            print(f"man {i+1} is matched with woman {j+1}")
    if pulp.value(mu_i0[i]) == 1:
        print(f"man {i+1} stays single")

for j in range(J):
    if pulp.value(mu_0j[j]) == 1:
        print(f"woman {j+1} stays single")```


Thanks a lot! This is very helpful. Do you think this algorithm will work with large I and J? Say I = J = 100K. In practice, I found the Auction algorithm (Bertsekas, 1998) works pretty well on the problem with no singles with large (but sparse) I and J (sparse in the sense that most pairs are not optional). If you have more ideas or references, please let me know

I'm not sure. This computation took 0.01 seconds on my laptop. I could try to increase the number of men and women and graph all points to get a function. If I get the equation of the function, I'll be able to compute the time for 200k players. I'll let you know what I concluded. Btw why do you need that?

Yes, it would be great, thanks!
I work on a structural estimation of a marriage model. The main question is the impact of age at immigration and language knowledge on the probability of immigrants marrying natives.

You should account for homosexuals. Although that depends on whether marriage for them is legal.

I don't see them in the data...

Too bad ig. Anyways, i derived the function for the computation time. I tried to put 200k as an input and guess what - "Numeric value is greater than 1.79769E+308 and cannot be displayed properly." I tried to run the program at 200k players and "Unable to allocate 37.3 GiB for an array with shape (100000, 100000) and data type int32". You can see the data I used to derive the function here if you want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15NaTK_Mmwx0vV_grmPjGT7fSkDrRM4Rr8oW27FJp4Hk/edit?usp=sharing

Thank you for trying it for me, this is very nice of you! Yes, I think brute force algorithms like this collapse at around 5k individuals (at least in the standard assignment problem with no singles). I will ask another question more specifically about a version of the auction algorithm in this case. Thanks again!
